# Why is my sapply function building a vector of integers?

Tags: r, vector, sapply

I have two related questions -- I'm trying to learn R properly, so I'm doing some homework problems from an R course. They have us writing a function to return a vector of correlations:

```
example.function <- function(threshold = 0) {
  example.vector <- vector()
  example.vector <- sapply(1:30, function(i) {
    complete.record.count <- # ... counts the complete records in each of the 30 files.
    ## Cutting for space and to avoid giving away answers.
    ## a few lines get the complete records in each 
    ## file and count them. 
    if(complete.record.count > threshold) {
      new.correlation <- cor(complete.record$val1, complete.record$val2)
      print(new.correlation)
      example.vector <- c(new.correlation, example.vector)
    }  
  })
  # more null value handling#
  return(example.vector)
}
```

As the function runs it prints the correlation value to stdout. The values it prints are accurate to six decimal points. So I know I'm getting a good value for `new.correlation.` The vector that is returned doesn't include those values. Instead, it is whole numbers in sequence.

```
> tmp <- example.function()
> head(tmp)
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I can't figure out why `sapply` is pushing integers into the vector? What am I missing here?

I actually don't understand the core structure, which is more or less:

```
some.vector <- vector()
some.vector <- sapply(range, function(i) {
  some.vector <- c(new.value,some.vector)
}
```

that seems awfully un-R-like in its redundancy. Tips?

Comment: Nice question with code and all, but I am missing `complete.record.count`. Are you aware of the `str()` function?

Comment: Would love an explanation of the vote to close. I can't be the only person who is able to print a value but not add it to a vector.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are using `example.vector` both as your `sapply` output and as a global variable inside the function being applied. Read the doc for `sapply` and the example: it is not meant to work that way. I voted to close as I find your question too localized, i.e., unlikely to help any future visitor in its current format. Also if instead of a lengthy and non-reproducible example you had tried to break down your problem to something small, you might have found what you are doing wrong by yourself.

Comment: Yes, the last part is awful, it should just be `some.vector <- sapply(range, function(i) {[...]; return(new.value)}`. Do not use `some.vector` anywhere else, especially inside the body of the function to be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `sapply` you don't need to create the vector yourself and you don't need to grow it (`sapply` takes care of all that). You probably want something like this:

```
example.function <- function(threshold = 0) {
  example.vector <- sapply(1:30, function(i) {
    ## Cutting for space and to avoid giving away answers.
    ## a few lines get the complete records in each 
    ## file and count them. 
    if(complete.record.count > threshold) {
      new.correlation <- cor(complete.record$val1, complete.record$val2)
      }  else {
        new.correlation <- NA   
      }
    new.correlation #return value of anonymous function
  })
  # more null value handling#
  example.vector #return value of example.function
}
```

However, it is unclear how the index `i` factors into the anonymous function and the question is not reproducible ...

Comment: this is helpful. I'll rework the example so it is actually reproducible.